# Can we deploy a private blockchain on ethereum without using smart contract

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, raft

I'm recently trying to investigate whether we can deploy a private blockchain without using the functionality of the smart contract, or in that case can we deploy it on quorum without the functionality of smart contract

Comment: Your question is not clear , maybe you looking for something similar to plasma chains

Answer (score 0):

A private blockchain is independent from a smart contract. You can run your own private Ethereum network (for example using ganache, geth or parity). To ensure (others) that you don't randomly rollback in a network based on Proof-of-Authority  or a low computation power Proof-of-Work consensus mechanism (for example), you can send a transaction to a strong network like Ethereum every N blocks, including the latest block hash of your private chain in the transaction data.